# Angular2/Angular seed http-proxy-middleware proxy api requests

Tags: api, angular, proxy, http-proxy-middleware

Im using the [Angular Seed project](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/tree/master/tools) and trying to set up a proxy for api requests for a backend service that is running on a different port.

My code so far:

```
/* Add proxy middleware */
this.PROXY_MIDDLEWARE = [
  require('http-proxy-middleware')({
    ws: false,
    target: 'http://localhost:5555',
    router: {
      // when request.headers.host == 'dev.localhost:3000',
      // override target 'http://www.example.org' to 'http://localhost:8000'
      //'http://localhost:5555/basepath/api' : 'http://localhost:7000/api'
    }
  })
];
```

Basically what I need to do is route any api matching http://localhost:5555/basepath/api to http://localhost:7000/api though I cant seem to get this working using http-proxy-middleware.  I had it originally working using proxy-middleware but have switched as i need to modify the request headers and it seems that can only be done with http-proxy-middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent a bit of time trying to get this work and this is what I ended up adding to project.config.ts within the constructor.

```
   /* Add proxy middleware */
    this.PROXY_MIDDLEWARE = [
      require('http-proxy-middleware')(
        '/basepath/api', {
        ws: false,
        onProxyReq: this.onProxyReq,
        target: 'http://localhost:7000',
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/basepath/api' : '/api'
        }
      })
    ];
```

And this is the function I included below the constructor to add header to any requests that are proxied

```
onProxyReq(proxyReq: any , req: any, res: any) {
  // add custom headers to request
  proxyReq.setHeader('header_name', 'value');
}
```